# Javascript from external file not loading

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, load

I have a problem with Javascript that keeps bugging me for quite a while now. I have an external file called search.js which is in the same folder as the .html file it's loaded into.

The piece of code I use in th HTML to load the javascript file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

From all the websites I've read I can't find an issue here with the code.

Also, I know that the syntax in the javascript file has to be correct in order for it to work, so here is my Javascript code from *search.js*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){
        var lookfor = $("#billSearched").val();
        alert(lookfor);
        var a = $(this).attr('action');
        alert(a);
        a = a.replace("__search_term__",lookfor);
        alert(a);
        window.location.href = a;
        return false;
    });
});
```

I've runned this code in another project and it has worked just fine, all that I've changed was the names of the fields, i.e. billSearched.

If there are any other reasons for why Javascript doesn't load in my page please leave a message or a comment.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Full html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bills</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/search.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body bgcolor="#0066CC" color="FFFFFF">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:white"><b>Products</b></td>
            <td style="color:white">Price</td>
            <form method="POST" id="searchForm"  action="{% url ps.views.search searchTerm='__search_term__' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <td><input type="text" id="billSearched"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Search"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        {% for x in products %}
        <tr>
        <td style="color:white">{{ x.name }}</td>
        <td style="color:white">{{ x.price }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Anything in the console? Are you loading jquery on that page, and loading it before search.js?

Comment: Is it linked correctly? When you look at the JS files with the net tab, does it show it as a 200? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: yes, I am loading jquery right before search.js and still nothing appears on the page. I'm using Firebug to check if .js has loaded.

Comment: Got a link to a live example? It can be a number of things that cause your issue. You've mis-typed where the script is. You have a BASE tag somewhere that affect the relative URL, or you've loaded jQuery after the search.js script... anything. We need more information.

Comment: can you add `alert('loaded');` just before `$('#searchForm')` ?

Comment: In your HTML example your search script is prefixed with / `/search.js` while your jQuery script is not. Is this correct?

Comment: Sometimes I also have, but Ctrl + F5 resolves my problem, may be your browser not loaded this and also check this in Firebug's `Net` panel

Comment: @Ahsan I've tried CTRL+F5 many times, restarting Firefox and even restarting my system, clearing Firefox cache.

Comment: @thomthom I've checked that, put a "/" in front of jQuery and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Any chance of a live example?

Comment: I don't know any free django webservers, and I can't run it from home

Comment: @thomthom what else would you want me to share?

Comment: Just to recap, Firebug shows that jQuery loads, but not search.js? And no errors in the Console? And if you used the full path for the script? Does that make a difference?

Comment: You are using django? How is your webserver serving the media?

Comment: @thomthom No, jQuery doesn't load either..

Comment: @pastylegs Well, I can see on the terminal that the server can access the files and GETs them.. but I can't see anything in my browser or firebug

Comment: So, you have the files in your root? (Seeing how you got the fienames prefixed with `/` ) Only thing I can image is that the reference to the JS files are incorrect or you disabled JS for that site...

Comment: Just for the sake of it, try with a different browser? In case there is something configured that blocks the scripts...

Comment: @thomthom The project structure is project/ps/templates/search.js and the .html file is in the same folder (project/ps/templates/bill.html)

Comment: this isn't a good idea if you are using Django. When you come to server your website for real, anyone will be able to see your templates

Comment: @pastylegs This is just a test project, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make a mix of your answers in order to fix the problem but eventually it was fixed. I had to make the following modifications:

- Add the '/static/' folder to STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS in the settings.py file
- Import the .js files (search.js and the jQuery source) with the following commands, in this order:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/search.js"></script>
  ```
- And make the according file structure, placing the "static" file in the project's root directory.

  i.e. 
  Psroot:
- psApp
- static
- templates
- and the rest of the files (settings.py, urls.py, manage.py, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

From the tags and your template code, I gather that you are using Django. To understand your issue, you'll have to understand how Django views work relative to your browser, and what happens when your browser issues a request for a given url.

### What happens on the `Django` side:

What happens when you request an url is that your base `urls.py` file will be searched for pattern matching your url. If a pattern is encountered, then the corresponding `view` will be called.
The `view`will carry out its logic, and will use a `template` to render its response into `html`.

### What happens from your browser's point of view

The browser requested an url, and received a response, it is not aware of the fact that a view was called, and that it fetched a template somewhere.

### What this means to you

The fact that your `search.js` file is located next to your template is **totally irrelevant**, as your browser **never requested any file from this directory**, it's the `view` that did, when it fetched its `template`.

Actually, your browser's request for `search.js` will be forwarded to `Django` by your webserver and will (most likely) result in a `404` error, unless `search.js` resolves to a view in your `urls.py`.

### How you can use this to solve your issue

You'll need to serve your `search.js` file from a directory that can be accessed by the browser. Usually, this is done in three steps:

1. Configure your webserver so that it serves any path starting with `/static/` on its own (somehow, this means not forwarding the request to `Django`).
   In Apache, you'd use the following rule: `Alias /static/ /YOUR/STATIC/DIRECTORY/`
2. Configure `Django`'s `settings.py` to use `/YOUR/STATIC/DIR` as `STATIC_ROOT`,  and `/static/` as `STATIC_URL`.
3. Put your `search.js` file in your `/YOUR/STATIC/DIR/`
4. Use `src="/static/search.js` to reference your file in your `html` template.

One last thing: if you're using the development server, you might need to ensure your `STATIC_URL` starts with the full path to your server, including the port. (Or you might have issues with browser security policies).

### A few additions:

Your should be using template tags so that you don't have to write `/static/` in your template.
You should be using `manage.py collectstatic` to autimatically put static files in your static directory.

Most importantly, **you should investigate what Django's MVC (or MTV) model is about**.

Comment: And what about `STATIC_ROOT` and webserver configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Paths prefixed with `/` points to the root - not the current folder. In this case you want to drop the `/` prefix.

Your HTML files at `project/ps/templates/bill.html` which links a JS script `/search.js` means it's looking for the files in the completely wrong location.

For instance, you can see how it resolves the path if you add a link to `/search.js` in your HTML.

For illustrative purposes, create an HTML file on your desktop:

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="/foobar.txt">Hello</a>
<a href="foobar.txt">World</a>

</body>
</html>
```

When you hover over the link you will see that `Hello` it resolves to `file:///foobar.txt` and `World` resolves to the path to your desktop - in my case `file:///C:/Users/thm.ARC/Desktop/foobar.txt`.

Comment: Ok, i've dropped the / in both situations and now I'm loading them directly src="search.js", and with jQuery it's the same thing but no result.

Comment: And if you use absolute paths?

Comment: I've tried it in my freshly installed Chrome with firebug add-on and I see that Chrome finds the files, jQuery and search.js but it says "Access to restricted URI denied."

Comment: Or, if you add a link to the script - if you click it - does it load the script or do you get a 404? If you do get a 404, what does your error log say? what URL is requested and how is it compared to the URL of the scripts?

Comment: Yes, I get a 404. The error log says:Page not found (404)
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/search.js

Using the URLconf defined in psdemo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^$ [name='bills']
    ^search/(?P<searchTerm>\w*) [name='search']

The current URL, search.js, didn't match any of these.