# External file Javascript Not Loading

Tags: javascript, django-staticfiles

I'm using django development server to study how to create template. But my local js file not loading. The js is working fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesliam/PARWP/1/).

Here's my html file.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/encoder_view.css" %}" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--This external file-->
<script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static "js/encoder_view.js" %}"></script> 

</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr id="top-border">       
  <td width="120">     
    <input id="check-all" class="checkbox" name="selector" type="checkbox" style="width:15px;"/>
     <span id="testcheck">Check All</span>
  </td>    
 </tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Following [Thomas Orozco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9737076/2074141) instruction
and after using `manage.py collectstatic` all my static files is now in D:\Test_app\static
directory

In my settings.py file:

STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/Test_app/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( "D:/Test_app/static",)

INSTALLED_APPS = ( 'django.contrib.staticfiles', ...

Can anyone give me direction how to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/encoder_view.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks Gimmy, hardcoding the url did the job. I was in the impression the {% static "js/encoder_view.js" %} will do this automatically.

Comment: You can look at the source produced to check that the url was composed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late, but another possible solution to this would be to change "scr" to "src" in `<script type="text/javascript" scr="{% static "js/encoder_view.js" %}"></script>`.